# Unable to download audio with MediaLibraryExtensions.SaveSong in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

I am trying to download an audio and saving to isolated storage and saving to emulator.

I tried with the following code.

```
WebClient m_webClient = new WebClient();
m_webClient.OpenReadAsync(fileUri);
m_webClient.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(webClient_ImageOpenReadCompleted);
m_webClient.AllowReadStreamBuffering = true;  


private static void webClient_ImageOpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
        var isolatedfile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(_fileName, System.IO.FileMode.Create, isolatedfile))
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[e.Result.Length];
            while (e.Result.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) > 0)
            {
                stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
        }
        SaveFileMP3(_fileName);
}

private static void SaveFileMP3(string _fileName)
{
        MediaLibrary lib = new MediaLibrary();
        Uri songUri = new Uri(_fileName, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        MediaLibraryExtensions.SaveSong(lib, songUri, null, SaveSongOperation.CopyToLibrary);

}
```

The problem I am facing is, the audio getting saved to the emulator but not with the extension. Suppose the file name "test.MP3", it is saved as "test" and the duration is always 0:0:00 irrespective to the original duration.

I have added Audio capability too in the manifest file.

Following is the screenshot while saving the song, which has many exceptions in it.

[image]

Please correct if something is wrong with code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding the line of lib.savesong worked perfectly instead of using mediaLibraryExtensions.

```
private static void SaveFileMP3(string _fileName)
{
    MediaLibrary lib = new MediaLibrary();
    Uri songUri = new Uri(_fileName, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
    lib.SaveSong(songUri, null, SaveSongOperation.CopyToLibrary);
    //MediaLibraryExtensions.SaveSong(lib, songUri, null, SaveSongOperation.CopyToLibrary);

}
```